# how to create a panel at runtime which includes button textbox label timer using c#.net

Tags: c#, timer, runtime, panel, cloning

```
private void Add_Timer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    number_of_timer++;
    for (int i = 1; i < number_of_timer; i++)
    {
        Panel pnl = new Panel();

        Control c2 = new Control();
        pnl.Location = new Point(12, 175*i+25);
        pnl.BorderStyle = panel1.BorderStyle;
        pnl.BackColor = panel1.BackColor;
        pnl.Size = panel1.Size;
        pnl.Visible = true;              
        foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                c2 = new TextBox();
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                c2 = new Button();
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                c2 = new Label();    
            if(c.GetType()== typeof(Timer))
                Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick); 
            c2.Location = c.Location;
            c2.Size = c.Size;
            c2.Font = c.Font;
            c2.Text = c.Text;
            c2.Name = c.Name;
            pnl.Controls.Add(c2);
            this.Controls.Add(pnl);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a panel using this but I am unable to access the buttons which are created at runtime.

Comment: Doing it this way makes little sense.  Create a UserControl instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *unable to access the Buttons* I guess you mean you don't have a `Click` event for them?

You simply need to add it, like you did for the `Timer`:

```
if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
{
    c2 = new Button();
    c2.Click += cloneButtonsClick;
}
```

This creates a common `Click` event for all `Buttons`.

Therefore in the event you will need to check on which button it was that was `pressed`, assuming there are more than one. You can do that by its `Name` (if you have set it) or its `Text`. (Or any other property you have set, like e.g. the `Tag`) After casting `sender` to `Button` you can do the tests and code your click actions..:

```
void cloneButtonsClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button bt = sender as Button;
     if (bt == null) return;                           // this should never happen!
     /* if (bt.Name == "saveButton")  { do your things; } // one way to test..   */
     if (bt.Text== "Save")         { do your things; } // ..another way to test
     else if (bt.Text== "Load")    { do your things; } // ..another way to test
     //..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to create a panel in application. If I get you right, you need to get buttons in another block of code. So you can use linq-expression:

```
var buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().Where(x => x is Panel).SelectMany(x => x.Controls).OfType<Button>();
```

Or you can store them in local variable to quick access, when you create it:

```
if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
{
    c2 = new Button();
    buttons.Add(c2);     // where buttons is List<Button>();
}
```

But I think the best descision will be to create a UserControl (copy of panel1) instead of multiply instances of dynamic panel and extract some properies/events to outside.